# Scraping tables from Multiple URLs

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup

Hi I've been able to scrape tables and export them from a specific website but would like to add more websites to scrape from. It only returns the second URL I put in. Apologies in advance since I'm very new to Python. Thank you.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd

urls = ['http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/BScanItemsRequiredServlet?requestid=7&defaultdisplay=y&passjobnumber=123821098&passdocnumber=01&allbin=1015650', 'http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/BScanItemsRequiredServlet?requestid=6&defaultdisplay=y&passjobnumber=121054170&passdocnumber=01&allbin=1015650']

for url in urls:
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}
    page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find_all('table')[3]
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, The issue here that you are looping over the `tables` without appending. and then you are `printing` out.

**Example**:

```py
for item in range(1, 4):
    pass

print(item)
```

Now the output is:

```
3
```

Because it's the last returned element from the `loop`.

But, if we append like the following:

```py
result = []
for item in range(1, 4):
    result.append(item)

print(result)
```

So we will get the following:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Now, let's move to the next point, you already can read the `table` directly using [pandas.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) because `urllib3` is already within the background of `pandas` , as the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(
    "http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/BScanItemsRequiredServlet?requestid=7&defaultdisplay=y&passjobnumber=123821098&passdocnumber=01&allbin=1015650")[3]

print(df)
```

But since the website `TCP` layer is configured to `Connection: close` [ref](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

> HTTP/1.1 defines the "close" connection option for the sender to signal that the connection will be closed after completion of the response. For example,

```
   Connection: close
```

So we will run that under `requests` library with maintaining the `Session` object to not getting blocked by the `server` firewall using `requests.Session()` and appending the `table` for each `url` and then concatenated it in one `table` using `pd.concat` function and then convert to `csv` `using pd.to_csv()`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

urls = ['http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/BScanItemsRequiredServlet?requestid=7&defaultdisplay=y&passjobnumber=123821098&passdocnumber=01&allbin=1015650',
        'http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/BScanItemsRequiredServlet?requestid=6&defaultdisplay=y&passjobnumber=121054170&passdocnumber=01&allbin=1015650']

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'
}


def main(urls):
    goal = []
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for url in urls:
            r = req.get(url, headers=headers)
            df = pd.read_html(r.content)[3]
            goal.append(df)
    goal = pd.concat(goal)
    goal.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)


main(urls)
```

Output: [View Online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/2145da52968058136045f22dfab07995/data.csv)

[image]

Code updated as per **User** Request:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

urls = ['http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/BScanItemsRequiredServlet?requestid=7&defaultdisplay=y&passjobnumber=123821098&passdocnumber=01&allbin=1015650',
        'http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/BScanItemsRequiredServlet?requestid=6&defaultdisplay=y&passjobnumber=121054170&passdocnumber=01&allbin=1015650']

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'
}


def main(urls):
    goal = []
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for url in urls:
            r = req.get(url, headers=headers)
            df = pd.read_html(r.content)[2:4]
            for table in df:
                goal.append(table)
    goal = pd.concat(goal)
    goal.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)


main(urls)
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/93d585280ab24a665b21503781bd25a2/data.csv)

Comment: Wow thank you!! You even help me get through the server issue! Much appreciated!

Comment: one last question. I want to add the "Job number" for each row of the data it's pulled from. I've been using

```
   job_no = soup.find('td',{'class':'maininfo','align':'right'})
   links = job_no.find('a')
```

I'm trying to grab the text from the a href. How can I populate it to each row of the data table? Thank you so much again.

Comment: @eGami you've received an answer based on the question which you've asked. for a record on future posts, Kindly include all the details and please show some effort to avoid being going from issue to another, as `Stackoverflow` community is not code writing service or assigning homework or work assignments. and in case if that is your desired [output](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/93d585280ab24a665b21503781bd25a2/data.csv) , let me know.

Comment: understood and I apologize for your frustration. It is indeed what I was looking for. Sorry as I'm completely new to this and the community. Will know better for next time. Thank you once again!